# Custom drawer icon flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make the drawer icon bigger than the default size and I'm using `width: MediaQuery.of (context) .size.width * 0.85` but it doesn't work and I don't know why. Then I'd like to have `ListView` coming from the left and not the right, but I need the menu icon to be on the right. How can I do this?

```
endDrawer: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
        child: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children:  <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Drawer Header',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 24,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.message),
                  title: Text('Messages'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => StantonPlanet()));
                  }
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                title: Text('Profile'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                title: Text('Settings'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ListView coming from the left and not the right"?

Comment: Here, the sidebar starts from the right to finish on the left, instead I want to start on the left and finish on the right https://imgur.com/a/GygwllG

Comment: Understood, and what about the Drawer Icon? Can you share the code you have right now for that as well?

Comment: To set the right drawer I used `endDrawer` (see above) but when I press the button to open the sidebar it opens it from the right, because I believe it is a property of` endDrawer` and I don't know how to "force" an opening from left to right holding the button on the right. Whit `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,` i was trying to make the icone bigger but it doesn't work

Comment: I Understand that. you mention an issue with Icon size, but in the code above I'm not able to see an Icon used.

Comment: oh ok, the `Drawer` automatically adds the hamburger icon to a default size. I haven't added any icons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233859/discussion-between-rohan-thacker-and-trf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a fix

```
appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    //backgroundColor: red,
    toolbarHeight: 120,
    centerTitle: false,
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu_rounded),
        iconSize: 35,
        onPressed: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer()
      ),
    ],
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      iconSize: 35,
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
    ),
    title: Text('App Bar', style: TextStyle(color: white, fontSize: 30,),),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
        bottom: Radius.circular(30),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title:Text('hi'),
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
      onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: it gives me this error: `Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.`

Comment: You can use global key also `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> key;' and use this key in key property of scaffold class. Now you can use **key.currentState.openDrawer** instead of Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()